# salesforce application create a generic xpath using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, salesforce-lightning

This is the salesforce application, i want to click the admin menu, so below is the source

```
<li class="slds-context-bar__item slds-shrink-none" is="one-app-nav-bar-item-root">
<a class="slds-context-bar__label-action" href="#/n/admin" title="Admin" tabindex="0">
<span class="slds-truncate">Admin</span>
</a>
</li>
```

i framed below xpath using contains, but its not working

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Admin')]"));
```

I get the path from firepath/IDE, its working

```
@FindBy(how =How.XPATH, using = "//header[@id='oneHeader']/div[3]/one-appnav/div/one-app-nav-bar/nav/ul/li[2]/a/span")
```

but i want to frame generic xpath with above html either using menu name or title (admin), please guid me, because in feature if any ul or li tag added in between its not working

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Admin']"));` or `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin"));`

Comment: Thanks Andersson for the notification, i forgot the linkText option

Comment: You can also use `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Admin']"));`

Comment: try `a[title='Admin']>span`, if you want  css way.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to identify the node with text as **`Admin`** you can use the following line of code :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='slds-context-bar__label-action' and @title='Admin']/span[@class='slds-truncate']"));
```